# How to keep the value of the variable every time I run the program?

Tags: python

I wrote code bellow in python:

```
static=''
def write(value):
    static+=value
    print(static)
```

I want not to destroy the value of the static variable after each program execution, and add new information.I do not want use  file for it.
How can do it?

Comment: Save the value to file, then read it back when you start the program.

Comment: There is literally no possible way to do it without using a file.

Comment: ... or a database, or environment variable, or some other form of external storage.

Comment: What are you trying to do outside of this question?

Comment: As the dupe suggests, use pickle.

Comment: You need some form of data storage, a python script cannot store data in itself. It stores in memory while it is running, as soon as it is done that memory is available to the os. If you need it stored beyond that you need some other data storage, a file, a database, something.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ For something as simple as a single string value, using `pickle` seems like over kill. Just store the string in a file, and read it back. Of course, in reality the OP will probably have more variables and more complex data structures, in which case using `pickle` is the absolutely best option.

Comment: @ChristianDean Correct. The takeaway is that a file is needed, no matter what the storage method, be it json, pickle, or w/e.